# how to know if a spinlock is held in kernel space

Tags: concurrency, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, spinlock

I'm writing a Linux Devide Driver using NVIDIA API, and I notice that there's a function that fails if I call it holding a spinlock. I was asking myself, how a kernel function knows if it's called holding a spinklock?

maybe better if I go with an pseudocode example:

```
spin_lock_irqsave(&my_lock,flags)
nvidia_p2p_get_pages(...)
spin_unlock_irqrestore(&my_lock, flags)
```

the function p2p_get_pages in this situation returns an error (but it works if I use it without the spinlock... anyway this is not the problem).

What could happen inside that function that fails? maybe it tries to take another spinlock? or sleep? or it checks for spinlocks... and how? how can it knows about the spinlock?

thank you!

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `spin_lock` and `spin_lock_irqsave`?

Comment: `spin_lock()`   -   *Acquires given lock*
    `spin_lock_irqsave()`   -   *Saves current state of local interrupts, disables local interrupts, and acquires given lock*

so how this helps in my question? the function inside checks for the state of interrupts?

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to check whether a specific lock is locked by calling `spin_is_locked()`.
However, it is unlikely that the nvidia driver knows about your `my_lock`.

Many functions care only about the fact that they (might) need to sleep.
This would blow up when in an atomic context (i.e., when interrupts are disabled).
To detect this, many such functions call `might_sleep()` to log a warning before bad things actually happen.
(`might_sleep()` does not know about your locks either, it just checks whether interrupts are disabled.)

Comment: I tried this snippet:
`might_sleep();                              
spin_lock_irqsave(&my_lock,flags);  
might_sleep();`
but nothing is printed, neither before nor after the lock... anyway it should print a stack trace, right? I still can't understand how the nvidia module can generate the error, it is impossible that the nvidia module can know `my_lock`.

Comment: if I call the nvidia_p2p_get_page with a spinlock held, it returns -EINVAL. without spinlock, it returns SUCCESS. how can it knows that I'm holding a spinlock before the call?

Comment: It just checks whether interrupts are disabled.